# Asciidoctor: store git commit hash in pdf

Tags: documentation, asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I'd like to generate a PDF from an `.adoc` file with asciidoctor using

`asciidoctor-pdf Doku.adoc`

How can I print the current git sha1-hash into the PDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [DocumentAttributes](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/attributes/document-attributes/)

`asciidoctor-pdf -acommitHash=$(git rev-parse HEAD) Doku.adoc`

You can now use the document attribute `commitHash` within your document by writing:

`{commitHash}`

Use `ifdef` to test if the variable is set.

```
ifdef::commitHash[]
{commitHash}
endif::[]
```

You can also define a default as fallback if no attribute is defined from the CLI

```
:commit: Unknown
Version: {commit}
```

The command line `-a` will override the document internal declaration.